# sqlite android query (cursor)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, service, cursor

I developed an application that allows the user to save his two favourite parking spots. It uses a service to retrieve the relevant parking information from an sqlite database. Within the database I have this method to find the first entry:

```
  public Cursor firstentry(){
       String select = "SELECT PREF1, PREF2 FROM parking_table WHERE id =1";
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select, null);
   return cursor;
```

Every time I run my application a force close error appears, when the service tries calling this method using the command:

```
Cursor c = dh.firstentry();
```

It is giving the error as when I comment it, the applications works perfectly.

Here is the logcat of the error:

```
04-08 18:56:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(13166): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
04-08 18:56:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(13166): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 18:56:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(13166):    at stefan.testservice.ConnectionService$1.run(ConnectionService.java:64)
04-08 18:56:38.673: E/AndroidRuntime(13166):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166): Activity stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity has leaked IntentReceiver stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity$2@40521b78 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity has leaked IntentReceiver stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity$2@40521b78 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:756)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:551)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:795)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:782)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:776)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity$1.onServiceConnected(TestserviceActivity.java:280)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1064)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1081)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-08 18:56:39.654: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166): Activity stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity has leaked ServiceConnection stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity$1@40521790 that was originally bound here
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity has leaked ServiceConnection stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity$1@40521790 that was originally bound here
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:938)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:833)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:867)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity.doBindService(TestserviceActivity.java:290)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at stefan.testservice.TestserviceActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(TestserviceActivity.java:193)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-08 18:56:40.054: E/ActivityThread(13166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is much appreciated as I tried everything and nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance!

Edited:

Parking table code:

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, PREF1 TEXT, PREF2 TEXT)");
  }
```

Comment: post your parking_table definition. Have you followed that the cursor requires the id of the table to be referenced exactly as _ID ?

Comment: please correct me if I understood you wrongly, are you suggesting that I need to have '_id = 1' instead of 'id = 1'?

Comment: ConnectionService.java line 64..post that line..

Comment: I posted that line, it's this :

Cursor c = dh.firstentry();

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. Although you need the _id if you use CursorAdaptor. Anyways it's good to use "android.provider.BaseColumns._ID" for your table ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, everything was ok, I just needed to initiliaze the class object. Here's the line of code needed:

```
this.yourobject = new class(this);
```

in my case it is:

```
this.dh = new SQLHelper(this);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

its a `nullpointerexception` meaning there is probably nothing in the database at that time. you need to handle if the cursor is null

stepping through the code is really the only way to see exactly what is null. More code is definitely needed though its hard to tell with what you posted

Comment: Hi, there is data, as the service starts with a delay and I also tested it by inserting dummy data myself to make sure that an empty database is not the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are running rawsql so check if the exact query is valid for your db , `SELECT PREF1, PREF2 FROM parking_table WHERE id =1`

are PREF1 exactly(with case) the name of columns ??

Comment: yes yes, the sql is correct and so are the names of the columns

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a SQLite browser software, get one here:
[SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

It helps when I'm working with SQLite. I've run into this problem before and I solved it by adding the `id` parameter into the query. Essentially, you'll want to change your query to:

```
public Cursor firstentry(){
   String select = "SELECT id, PREF1, PREF2 FROM parking_table WHERE id =1";
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select, null);
return cursor;
```

Don't forget to call `c.moveToFirst()` if `c` is the name of the Cursor.